# How to check if one of the query is in the range of data in PHP MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

i have some problem here ,

How to check either one of the input is in the range of data ? The first **if statement** only execute if the both data **has the same value** or **both data is in between the range of data**

**But it does not execute if one of the data is in the range**

**My question is , how to check whether one of the input is between the range ?**

The code as below :

```
<?php
    $connect      = mysqli_connect("", "root", "", "");
    global $connect;   

    if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
        $time_out   = $_POST['time_out'];
        $time_enter = $_POST['time_enter'];

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
        $get = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
        if($get && mysqli_num_rows($get) > 0 ){              
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get)){

            $time_out_db    = $row['time_out'];
            $time_enter_db  = $row['time_enter'];

                if(($time_out >= $time_out_db) && ($time_enter <= $time_enter_db))
                {
                    echo "Time is in between";
                }
                else if (){
                    echo "Either one of the time_out or time_enter is in the range";
                }
            }
            mysqli_free_result($get);           
        }else{
            echo "Nothin here !";
        }
    }
?>
<form action="time.php" method="post">  
    <table> 
        <tr>
            <td><i class="fa fa-unlock-alt"></i> </td>
            <td>Time out : </td>
            <td><input type ="text" name="time_out" size="30"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><i class="fa fa-unlock-alt"></i> </td>
            <td>Time enter : </td>
            <td><input type ="text" name="time_enter" size="30"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>    

    <p><input class="btnSuccess" type ="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"> </p>             
</form>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Change the AND with OR in ur query !

Comment: Already did, but it fails to run other input other than that :)

Comment: Past ur query with OR here pls :)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to paste query here , but the code does not display error if one of the input is in between . It just skip the statement and run the available echo ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `or` (`||`) condition in your second `if`:

```
<?php
    $connect      = mysqli_connect("", "root", "", "");
    global $connect;   

    if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
        $time_out   = $_POST['time_out'];
        $time_enter = $_POST['time_enter'];

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
        $get = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
        if($get && mysqli_num_rows($get) > 0 ){              
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get)){

            $time_out_db    = $row['time_out'];
            $time_enter_db  = $row['time_enter'];

                if(($time_out >= $time_out_db) && ($time_enter <= $time_enter_db))
                {
                    echo "Time is in between";
                }
                else if (($time_out >= $time_out_db) || ($time_enter <= $time_enter_db)){
                    echo "Either one of the time_out or time_enter is in the range";
                }
            }
            mysqli_free_result($get);           
        }else{
            echo "Nothin here !";
        }
    }
?>
<form action="time.php" method="post">  
    <table> 
        <tr>
            <td><i class="fa fa-unlock-alt"></i> </td>
            <td>Time out : </td>
            <td><input type ="text" name="time_out" size="30"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><i class="fa fa-unlock-alt"></i> </td>
            <td>Time enter : </td>
            <td><input type ="text" name="time_enter" size="30"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>    

    <p><input class="btnSuccess" type ="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"> </p>             
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code.

```
if(($time_out_db>=$time_out) && ($time_enter<=$time_enter_db)){
    echo "Time is in between"
}elseif(($time_out_db>=$time_out) || ($time_enter<=$time_enter_db)){
    echo "Either one of the time_out or time_enter is in the range";
}
```